# Syncing speed of reading from DB and Writing to elasticsearch using Akka grpc stream

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, grpc, akka-stream

Here, we developed multi services each uses akka actors and communication between services are via Akka GRPC. There is one service which fills an in memory database and other service called Reader applies some query and shape data then transfer them to elasticsearch service for insertion/update. The volume of data in each reading phase is about 1M rows.
The problem arises when Reader transfers large amount of data so elasticsearch can not process them and insert/update them all.

I used akka stream method for these two services communication. I also use scalike jdbc lib and code like below to read and insert batch data instead of whole ones.

```
def applyQuery(query: String,mergeResult:Map[String, Any] => Unit) = {
  val publisher = DB readOnlyStream {
    SQL(s"${query}").map(_.toMap()).list().fetchSize(100000)
      .iterator()
  }

  Source.fromPublisher(publisher).runForeach(mergeResult)
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var batchRows: ListBuffer[Map[String, Any]] = new ListBuffer[Map[String, Any]]
val batchSize: Int = 100000
def mergeResult(row:Map[String, Any]):Unit = {
    batchRows :+= row

    if (batchRows.size == batchSize) {

      send2StorageServer(readyOutput(batchRows))
      batchRows.clear()
    }
  }

  def readyOutput(res: ListBuffer[Map[String, Any]]):ListBuffer[StorageServerRequest] = {

// code to format res  
  }
```

Now, when using 'foreach' command, it makes operations much slower. I tried different batch size but it made no sense. Am I wrong in using `foreach` command or is there any better way to resolve speed problem using akka stream, flow, etc.

Comment: many times slower... compared to what ?

Comment: Srry, I corrected my mistake. I measured time in two different senarios of eith batch size and without it. when I don't use batch size and the process of reading and writing is successfully completed it took about 3-4 minutes but after applying batch size it took at least more that 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that operation to be used to append to `ListBuffer` is

batchRows += row

but using `:+` does not produce bug but is very inefficient so by using correct operator, `foreach` is no longer slow, although the speed problem again exists. This time, reading data is fast but writing to elasticsearch is slow.

After some searches, I came up with these solutions: 
 1. The use of queue as  buffer between database and elasticsearch may help. 
 2. Also if blocking read operation until write is done is not costly,
    it can be another solution.